# Como mostra a primeira imagem do post - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme, script

Estou editando o tema para wordpress http://www.arrastheme.com/  porem surgiu um problema.

Minhas imagens estão hospedadas no picasa e linkadas no post.

As imagens não aparecem na home nem nos arquivos, apenas quando entra dentro do post que é possivel velas.

Tentei atraves desses 2 tutoriais fazer com que a imagem apareça, porem sem sucesso

Tutoriais:

http://www.wprecipes.com/how-to-get-the-first-image-from-the-post-and-display-it

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/get-the-first-image-from-a-post/

O script relacionado as imagens é esse:

```
<?php

/**
 * Containers for storing thumbnail types and its default sizes.
 * @since 1.4.4
 */
$arras_image_sizes = array();

function arras_add_default_thumbnails() {

    $single_thumbs = arras_get_single_thumbs_size();
    arras_add_image_size( 'single-thumb', __('Single Post Thumbnail', 'arras'), $single_thumbs[0], $single_thumbs[1] );
    arras_add_image_size( 'sidebar-thumb', __('Sidebar Widgets', 'arras'), 36, 36); 

    do_action('arras_add_default_thumbnails');
}

/**
 * Function to add image size into both theme system.
 * @since 1.4.4
 */
function arras_add_image_size($id, $name, $default_width, $default_height) {
    global $arras_image_sizes;

    $arras_custom_image_sizes = arras_get_option('custom_thumbs');

    // Check from options if a custom width and height has been specified, else use defaults
    if (isset($arras_custom_image_sizes[$id])) {
        $width = $arras_custom_image_sizes[$id]['w'];
        $height = $arras_custom_image_sizes[$id]['h'];
    } else {
        $width = $default_width;
        $height = $default_height;
    }

    $arras_image_sizes[$id] = array(
        'name'  => $name, 
        'w'     => $width, 
        'h'     => $height,
        'dw'    => $default_width,
        'dh'    => $default_height
    );

    add_image_size($id, $width, $height, true);
}

/**
 * Function to remove image size into both theme system.
 * @since 1.4.4
 */
function arras_remove_image_size($id) {
    global $arras_image_sizes, $_wp_additional_image_sizes;

    unset($arras_images_sizes[$id]);
    unset($_wp_additional_image_sizes[$id]);
}

/**
 * Function to get image size's name, width and height, default or custom.
 * @since 1.4.4
 */
function arras_get_image_size($id) {
    global $arras_image_sizes;

    return (isset($arras_image_sizes[$id])) ? $arras_image_sizes[$id] : false;
}


/**
 * Helper function to grab and display thumbnail from specified post
 * @since 1.4.0
 */
function arras_get_thumbnail($size = 'thumbnail', $id = NULL) {
    global $post, $arras_image_sizes;

    $empty_thumbnail = '<img src="' . get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/images/thumbnail.png" alt="' . get_the_excerpt() . '" title="' . get_the_title() . '" />';

    if ($post) $id = $post->ID;

    // get post thumbnail (WordPress 2.9)
    if (function_exists('has_post_thumbnail')) {
        if (has_post_thumbnail($id)) {
            return get_the_post_thumbnail( $id, $size, array(
                'alt'   => get_the_excerpt(), 
                'title' => get_the_title()
            ) );
        } else {
            // Could it be an attachment?
            if ($post->post_type == 'attachment') {
                return wp_get_attachment_image( $id, $size, false, array(
                    'alt'   => get_the_excerpt(), 
                    'title' => get_the_title()
                ) );
            }       
            // Use first thumbnail if auto thumbs is enabled.
            if (arras_get_option('auto_thumbs')) {
                $img_id = arras_get_first_post_image_id();
                if (!$img_id) return $empty_thumbnail;

                return wp_get_attachment_image($img_id, $size, false, array(
                    'alt'   => get_the_excerpt(), 
                    'title' => get_the_title()
                ) );
            }
        }
    }

    // go back to legacy (phpThumb or timThumb)
    $thumbnail = get_post_meta($id, ARRAS_POST_THUMBNAIL, true);

    $w = $arras_image_sizes[$size]['w'];
    $h = $arras_image_sizes[$size]['h'];

    if ($thumbnail != '') {
        if (!$arras_image_sizes[$size]) return false;   
        return '<img src="' . get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/library/timthumb.php?src=' . arras_timthumb_wpmu_image_src($thumbnail) . '&amp;w=' . $w . '&amp;h=' . $h . '&amp;zc=1" alt="' . get_the_excerpt() . '" title="' . get_the_title() . '" />';
    } else if (arras_get_option('auto_thumbs')) {
        if (!$arras_image_sizes[$size]) return false;

        $img_id = arras_get_first_post_image_id();
        if (!$img_id) return $empty_thumbnail;

        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($img_id, 'full', false);
        if ($image) {
            list($src, $width, $height) = $image;
            return '<img src="' . get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/library/timthumb.php?src=' . arras_timthumb_wpmu_image_src($src) . '&amp;w=' . $w . '&amp;h=' . $h . '&amp;zc=1" alt="' . get_the_excerpt() . '" title="' . get_the_title() . '" />';
        }
    }

    return $empty_thumbnail;    
}


/**
 * Function to convert image URLs into WPMU compatible URLs for Timthumb
 * @since 1.5.1
 */
function arras_timthumb_wpmu_image_src($url) {
    global $blog_id, $current_site;

    $uploads = wp_upload_dir();

    if ( isset($blog_id) && $blog_id > 0 ) {
        $split = explode( '/files/', $url);
        if ( isset($split[1]) ) {
            $url = 'http://' . $current_site->domain . $current_site->path . 'wp-content/blogs.dir/' . $blog_id . '/files/' . $split[1];
        }
    }

    return $url;
}

/**
 * Function to retrieve the first image ID from post.
 * @since 1.5.0
 */
function arras_get_first_post_image_id($id = NULL) {
    global $post;
    if (!$id) $id = $post->ID;

    $attachments = get_children('post_parent=' . $id . '&post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image');
    if (!$attachments) return false;

    $keys = array_reverse(array_keys($attachments));
    return $keys[0];
}

function arras_get_single_thumbs_size() {
    $layout = arras_get_option('layout');

    if ( strpos($layout, '1c') !== false ) {
        $size = array(930, 375);
    } else if ( strpos($layout, '3c') !== false ) {
        $size = array(465, 190);
    } else {
        $size = array(620, 300);
    }

    return apply_filters('arras_content_width', $size);
}

/* End of file thumbnails.php */
/* Location: ./library/thumbnails.php */
```

Answer (score 1):

O sistema de slider do Arras, assim como qualquer `featured-image` do Wordpress, funciona com imagens locais.

Ou seja, você deve fazer upload das imagens de destaque dentro do seu wp, usando o menu de Mídia.

[Aqui tem um artigo](http://www.djio.com.br/usando-uma-imagem-destacada-no-wordpress-miniatura-do-post/) que explica bem como fazer isso e como configurar seu theme com os thumbnails.